# Access to object in module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

Im doing some logic which parse json data to object and I want to expose in some module specific object outside that other module can use,
I try with the following which doesnt work,any other idea?

```
var jsonObject;

module.exports = {

    parse: function () {
    //here I do the parsing
    ....

    jsonObject = JSON.parse(res)

    ,
    //here I want to expose it outside
    jsonObj:jsonObject
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to expose the entire object, you build it like you would any other JavaScript object and then use module.exports at the end :

```
MyObj = function(){
   this.somevar = 1234;
   this.subfunction1 = function(){};
}
module.exports = MyObj;
```

If you just want to expose certain functions, you don't NEED to build it like an object, and then you can export the individual functions :

```
var somevar = 1234;
subfunction1 = function(){};
nonExposedFunction = function(){};
module.exports = {
   subfunction1:subfunction1,
   somevar:somevar
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you simply assign the result of `JSON.parse` to `this.jsonObj`:

```
module.exports = {
    parse: function (res) {
        this.jsonObj = JSON.parse(res);
    }
};
```

Using `this.jsonObj` you are exposing the JSON object to the outside and you can use your module in this way:

```
var parser = require('./parser.js'),
    jsonString = // You JSON string to parse...

parser.parse(jsonString);
console.log(parser.jsonObj);
```